# I want to write a c# logic for a discount related purchase option

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, logic

Here is the scenario.

There is a product (eg. Pen). Each pen costs 10$.For every 4 pens i buy, i get 10$ off. So if i buy 5 pens, I should be charged 40$. If purchased quantity is less than 4 there is no freebie. If someone buys more than 4 like 8, so the total charge should be 60$ and so on.

I require the logic in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not my employer.  So figure out your assignment yourself.

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to answer, you can just down vote the question and leave

Comment: It is proper etiquette to post why the downvote!

Comment: etiquette? Can see from your reply what that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use integer division:

```
decimal costs = 10m;
decimal numPens = 8;
decimal totalCosts = (numPens - (numPens / 4)) * costs;
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use this

(C# console application made in VS 2013)

```
        decimal price = 10m;
        decimal totalCosts = 0m;
        Console.WriteLine("please enter number of pens for purchase");
        decimal numPens = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (numPens != null)
        {


            decimal discount = (numPens / 4) * 10;
             totalCosts = (numPens * price) - discount;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(totalCosts);
```